# Exporting Feature Classes in SDE to shapefiles and tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, enterprise-geodatabase, table, relationship-class

How can I export feature classes and tables in SDE to shapefiles and tables?

I am able to export the feature classes to shapefiles based on an extent. The problem I am running into is, I want to only export features from the tables that are related the one of the feature class. The tables and feature classes in the SDE are related based on an unique ID. If there are 30 features in the extent - I want to export only the related 30 records in the tables.

I am working in ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you can see an active Relate from SDE to the table you need (use the Relate button on the Attribute table of SDE to check). Just defining relationships in the database does not insure that there is an active relate in your MXD.

With a Relate active, the feature class records should pass through the select to the related table records. Then use a tool that exports only selected table data, such as Copy Rows. Make sure the spatial select is a precondition of following steps. Honoring table selects in ModelBuilder is a little trickier than feature class selects, as you can't really drag a table from the TOC into MB. I had problems with MB exporting all the records rather than the selections, and used a table view creation step in MB, but Copy Rows is a simpler method.